# How to create a simple layout with sidebar

Tags: html, css

I'm looking to create a right sidebar on my page, however after going over multiple guides and I am still a stuck.  What's the best way and most browser/mobile-friendly way to create a sidebar with minimal code?

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">

<section id="content" class="content">

     {squarespace.main-content}

    <div id="sidebar" class="sidebar">

      <squarespace:block-field id="sidebarBlocks" columns="12" />

    </div>
</section>
```

And CSS

```
.wrapper {}
.content {}
#sidebar {}
```

Comment: Could you be more specific about the kind of layout you ant pls. Should it be responsive? what should the width of the wrapper be? should it be centered?...

Comment: + sidebar isn't a valid html (or html5) tag you were probably wanting to call it `aside`

Comment: I am looking to have the wrapper be 960px wide and I would like it to be responsive.  On mobile, the sidebar can drop below the content.

Answer (score 0):

Design your sidebar as a web usercontrol and put it inside the following div structure on to the masterpage.

```
 <div id="parentContainer">   
        <div id="sitebody" >
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder  runat="server" ID="MainContent" />    
        </div>
        <div id="sidebar">
            <uc1:ucSideBar ID="ucSideBar1" runat="server" />
        </div>
 </div>
```

Touch up the divs using css;

```
#sidebar
{
    float: left;
    height: 80%;
    width: 250px;
}
 #sitebody
{
    float: left;
    padding: 0 10px;
    width: 60%;
    height :80%;
}

 #parentContainer
 {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    width: 1500px;
 }
```

[to see this in fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5BK9L/)

Comment: see the edited code and try it in fiddle link just below the answer. This is just a template where once included in site.master, you can fill with anything as you add pages.

Answer (score 0):

A better approach would be to use a CSS table layout with a fixed or dynamic width sidebar like [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A7PYT/4/). This doesn't require any hacky float clearfixes and is [cross-browser compatible](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-table).

```
.page {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

.content, .nav {
    display: table-cell;
}

.content {
    width: 100%;
}

.nav {
    min-width: 200px; /* Specify a fixed or percentage width or min-width here if required */
}

/* Stack at smaller widths */
@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {    
    .nav {
        /* You could stack sidebar ontop of content using table-header-group instead */
        display: table-footer-group;
    }
}
```